# Migrating from ViewPager to ViewPager2 with FragmentStateAdapter causes visible screen yank and StrictMode to be triggered

Tags: android, material-design

I've followed the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) and [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8192680-viewpager2-in-android-getting-started) tutorial to migrate to `ViewPager2`. When swiping the 4 screens from left to right, there is a visible screen yank which is not a great user experience. I've used `strictmode` to measure the performance.

The documentation explicitly mentions that `createFragment` must provide a new `Fragment` each time so the implementation seems to be implemented correct.

**MainActivity:**

```
private fun initializeViewPager(items: List<Item>) {
    val tabAdapter = TabAdapter(this, items)
    viewPager2.adapter = tabAdapter

    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = items[position].abbreviation
    }.attach()


class TabAdapter(activity: AppCompatActivity, private val items: List<Item>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return items[position].getId()
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return VersesFragment.getInstance(items[position])
    }
}
```

**SomeFragment:**

```
class SomeFragment : DaggerFragment()  {

    var adapter: ItemAdapter? = null

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSomeBinding

    private lateinit var item: Item

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        handleArguments()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentSomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // 
        .. Setting of view elements using the serialized item
        //
    }

    private fun handleArguments() {
        val args = arguments
            ?: throw NullPointerException("getArguments() seems to be null. ARG_BIBLETRANSLATION needed!")

        if (!args.containsKey(ARG_BIBLETRANSLATION)) throw NullPointerException("getArguments() does not contain ARG_BIBLETRANSLATION!")

        item = args[ARG_BIBLETRANSLATION] as Item
    }

    companion object {

        const val ARG_MY_ITEM = "arg_my_item"

        fun getInstance(item: Item): Fragment {

            val fragment = VersesFragment()

            fragment.arguments = Bundle(2).apply {
                putSerializable(ARG_MY_ITEM, item)
            }

            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Just for completeness, here is the original code that *does* perform fine:

**MainActivity:**

```
val adapter = SomePagerAdapter(items as ArrayList<Item>)
viewPager.adapter = sdapter
```

**SomePagerAdapter:**

```
class SomePagerAdapter(private val items: ArrayList<Item>) : PagerAdapter() {
    
    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any { 
        // Same code as in SomeFragment
    }
}
```

The [tutorial from raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8192680-viewpager2-in-android-getting-started) is super simple, but when enabling
`strictmode`, it does get triggered, while `strictmode` does not get triggered with the old viewpager and the same code:

```
  private fun enableStrictMode() {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads()
            .detectDiskWrites()
            .detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build()
    )

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
      StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
          .detectNonSdkApiUsage()
          .detectAll()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.java

it seems the adapter caches fragments but does not pre-init views. forward scroll is janky, backward works fine. 1-> 2 -> 3 slow, 3 ->2 ->1 fine